# python opencv sliding window issue

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

Am making use of sliding/rolling window technique to devide the input image into equal chunks of given size so for that am making use of following function to devide image into specified window size.

```
def rolling_window(base_cord,test_image, window):
    """Very basic multi dimensional rolling window. window should be the shape of
    of the desired subarrays. Window is either a scalar or a tuple of same size
    as `arr.shape`.
    """
    windowsize_r = window[0]
    windowsize_c = window[1]
    chunk_arr = {}
    for r in range(0, test_image.shape[0] - windowsize_r, windowsize_r):
        for c in range(0, test_image.shape[1] - windowsize_c, windowsize_c):
            win = test_image[r:r + windowsize_r, c:c + windowsize_c]
            cord = (r+base_cord[0], c+base_cord[1])
            chunk_arr[cord] = win
    return chunk_arr
```

> So, this function returns me the window of specified size lets say
>   50x50 along with its base cordinates in dictionary format.

But problem is suppose I pass down the image of any odd size like 968x885 then spliting equal size chunks of size 50x50 will left some odd boundary pixels at the end of the image , the resuling image after first round of sliding window looks something like below.

### [image]

As we can see above , the pixels at right side are not chunked into window coz it's < 50x50 window size.

So what i want is to modify rolling_window function in order to form seperate window chunk for remaining pixels in every possible row/column. So how to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Changing `test_image.shape[0] - windowsize_r` to `test_image.shape[0]` in both the `for` loop would work fine, But keep in mind that now you will get index out of bounds issues, which you need to resolve using `max(r, test_image.shape[0]-1)` before cropping

Comment: thanx for your response I tried your solution it works fine, but it takes too long to proccess the entire image, as there are 4 rounds am performing itteratively on the same image, my main motto behind sliding window was to make my algo time effecient currently it takes appro. 8 sec. to proccess entire image in 4 rounds, but as per your solution it takes even more than 100 sec. it's too long I need effective solution in terms of time complexity.

Comment: Hi, before blaming me for the increased time, You must understand as to what I exactly said. I haven't done anything drastic which would increase the time by that folds. The issue is with your current implementation. In simple words I just changes `for i in xrange(5)` to `for i in xrange(6)`